# new_resource assignment in chefspec test

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I'm stuck on a chefspec test which steps into my lwrp below and asserts that it creates a directory.

```
describe 'mw-tomcat::chefspec' do

  let(:chef) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(step_into: ['mw_tomcat_tree']) do |node|
      node.set['mw']['domain'] = domain
      node.set['mw']['gemrepo'] = gemrepo
    end
  end

  let(:chef_run) { chef.converge(described_recipe) }

  it 'creates the catalina_base directory' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/apps/bweb/apps/instance1')
  end

done
```

The test works if I uncomment the line below, but fails when trying to get the value from new_resource.settings

```
action :create do
  settings = new_resource.settings
  catalina_base=settings['catalina_base']
  #catalina_base='/apps/bweb/apps/instance1'

  directory "#{catalina_base}" do
    mode 0755
    owner settings['user']
    group settings['group']
    recursive true
    action :create
  end

end
```

Is there a way in chefspec to pass in the new_resource value above?

Thanks for any help.

Edward

*Update

It fails with the following message:

```
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic directory resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic directory resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic directory resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic directory resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Directory]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic link resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Link]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Link]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources for generic link resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Resource::Link]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] DEBUG: resources that survived replacement include: [Chef::Resource::Link]
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 51)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/bin] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/conf] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/lib] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/logs] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/temp] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/webapps] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing directory[/work] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 77)
[2015-08-21T19:25:02+01:00] INFO: Processing link[/lib/BESTFilter] action create (/home/we_edqui/mw-chef-repo/cookbooks/mw-tomcat/providers/tree.rb line 109)
  creates the catalina_base directory (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) mw-tomcat::chefspec creates the catalina_base directory
     Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/apps/bweb/apps/instance1')
       expected "directory[/apps/bweb/apps/instance1]" with action :create to be in Chef run. Other directory resources:

         directory[]
         directory[/bin]
         directory[/conf]
         directory[/lib]
         directory[/logs]
         directory[/temp]
         directory[/webapps]
         directory[/work]

     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.80061 seconds (files took 4.72 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/default_spec.rb:67 # mw-tomcat::chefspec creates the catalina_base directory
```

The full output is at http://fpaste.org/257744/14401829/

Comment: can you give us more than "failed"?  What was the error, pasting the error message would be even better.

Comment: Yes sure! I will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [this](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/issues/522) pretty detailed ChefSpec bug report, what you are trying to do is probably not possible because the `new_resource` object is actually created dynamically at run time.

There is a [pretty complex workaround](https://www.omniref.com/github/felixbuenemann/chef/nofields-deploy/files/chef/spec/unit/provider/env_spec.rb) for this if you are determined to make it work, however the currently preferred method would be to convert your LWRP to an HWRP and use the standard RSpec methods for simulating input.

Comment: Thanks @eherot. Your answer was really helpful. Having read through the links and understood the complexity a bit more I'm not sure I am that determined to get this working although it would be nice. As I am wrapping this cookbook, I think I will move the chefspec test downstream and leave the LWRP testing for now.